Capture realtime traffic throughput usage Android
I'm trying to develop a simple app on Android that captures the realtime throughput traffic statistics per 500ms and sends it to my InfluxDB server. Although I've noticed that TrafficStats isn't very accurate. There's around 10% more traffic than what's outputting on iPerf3.
Is there another better approach to get realtime traffic usage?
public void writeDownloadThroughput() {
    if (!isOpen) {
        Log.e("InfluxDBManager", "InfluxDB client is not initialized. Please set credentials first.");
        return;
    }

    executorService.execute(() -> {

        long initialBytesReceived = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();


        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long finalBytesReceived = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();

        long bytesReceivedIn500ms = finalBytesReceived - initialBytesReceived;

        if (bytesReceivedIn500ms <= 0) {
            Log.d("InfluxDBManager", "No download throughput detected.");
            return;
        }

        long throughputInBytesPerSecond = bytesReceivedIn500ms * 2;  

        Log.d("InfluxDBManager", "Download Throughput: " + throughputInBytesPerSecond + " bytes/second");

        Point point = Point.measurement("network_throughput")
                .addTag("device", Build.MODEL)
                .addField("download_throughput", throughputInBytesPerSecond) 
                .time(Instant.now(), WritePrecision.MS);

        executorService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                writeApi.writePoint(point);  
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("InfluxDBManager", "Error writing to InfluxDB", e);
            }
        });
    });
}


WHy do you think that value is inaccurate?

I explained it because on iPerf3 the bitrate per second is 10% lower than what's shown in TrafficStats, somebody also noticed that in a stackoverflow question but no response.
